# Racket Terminal: Print unicode characters

Tags: racket

Is there a way to setup the racket terminal so that it can display unicode characters? It would be helpful, since Dr. Racket itself supports unicode file formats.

Comment: Which terminal are you starting racket in?

Comment: I am not sure what you want but when I type `> (display "क")` in my DrRacket 6.3 (in Ubuntu) I get `क`. More on Racket [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/strings.html) Is this what you want?.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Racket terminal itself i.e. when you run racket.exe a terminal pops up.

Comment: I'm not in DrRacket itself, just racket. When I type (display "λ") I get "?" back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
chcp 65001
```

before starting Racket. That should change the code page to UTF-8.

Comment: Do you know what the code-page is for "∀" "∃" and "λ"?

Comment: They ought to be displayed correctly on a utf-8 terminal?

Comment: Weird... I get a question mark in a box for these characters. I am running a Racket program in the terminal whose file encoding is saved as UTF-8.

Comment: It is able to echo lambda but not ∀. When I copy and paste it into the command line it turns into a question mark in a box.

Comment: Do you have the Lucinda Console font?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500#388500

Comment: I switched to using Lucida Console font. Still isn't printing properly.

Comment: I get an empty square where the "for all"s should be.